# Is it possible for a Perl DBI script to do "buffered inserts" on db2?

Tags: performance, perl, db2, dbi

[Buffered Inserts](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0204pooloth/0204pooloth.html) are a feature of db2 allowing one to get greater insert performance.  IBM's documentation describes needing to bind this option to your application.  I can't figure out if this is possible to do with the Perl DBI interface, and if it is possible, how to do it.

Comment: Are you accessing a database that uses the database partitioning feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buffered inserts are only applicable if you are using the DB2 Database Partitioning Feature, which is typically used only for data warehouses and other business intelligence applications.

That said, DBD::DB2 is written using the DB2 CLI (call level interface).  Therefore, it uses the standard system CLI packages to access the database.  It is *possible* to bind the standard CLI packages with buffered inserts, but this is usually not advisable because doing this will alter how errors are returned to ALL client applications.